# Normal/face bug total mistery

Tags: faces, normals, knife-tool

[image]

[image]

Original question go further in the post to see the edit 4 behaviour

(Hello, i have a problem with my meshes they suddenly appear to have **weird bug with normal** **only when i move my camera on axis like front or side** and i can't use a knife tool normaly it just rip off the face completely in all case and i tested a new file it work fine here,and my normal are correctly calculated.

ALl my mesh are hand made and i use a rigify workflow to animate for unreal, i made this work for a moment now and it probably work but not being able to use the knife tool is a pain

I have realy no idea but maybe its cause i m using the steam version of blender that keep up to date the software and maybe my mesh didnt liked it but i suspect a lot more something else

i also tried to check with the 3d print addon see if there is some weird thing going on but there is no problem, also it was working fine before i think its when i parented my mesh to my rig but i dont understand)

[image]

[image]

**Edit 4 : I just changed my layout to see the file and test thing and in this form everything work properly this is realy weird its the same files**

What drive this problem then i can't isolate it

To Resume current status :

When im in the first layout of my blend file everything work perfectly, i can knife tool anything and there is no problem of normal anywhere but the second i change the layout (shown in those screenshot under) those problem appear

[image][image]

Im gonna put more scrrenshot to illustrate but this is realy weird i dont know if someone could figure it out

[image]

[image]

**This thing on the upper screenshot doesnt occur as stated upper when im not picking a side with the camera but i actualy can't knife tool and my mesh have weird behaviour with face etc.. except when i m in the the first layout of my blend file where everything work properly**

Comment: This looks a lot like overlapping or corrupted geometries. If you isolate the corset ('*' key), does it look the same? If you recompute Normals (alt+N, recalculate outside) also?

Comment: i already did this i said normal are calculated correctly i tried those two thing a lot of time, it look like a parameter is coming to fuck this up cause as i say and show on the edit 4 everything work perfectly when im in this layout this is realy strange

Comment: Providing a file would go a huge way toward encouraging people to look at this in more detail.

Comment: Hey @Nathan I just uploaded the blendfile, i deleted almost everything except an example mesh, there is no rig with it but the bug or problem is here

Comment: @Flavie404 I can't reproduce your problem in the file you've provided.  I have only "V2.2_Fem_lp. no nipple push up.0016", without any mats, while normal maps and/or material settings may be part of the problem.  You also have some weird empty collections in there, suggesting maybe you didn't include everything you intended to include.  Making a mat for your single mesh object and inspecting, normals are fine.  Some of your screenshots look like Eevie alpha blend with show backface and without backface culling (which you shouldn't do, alpha blend can't be sorted well.)

Comment: @Nathan I included all i wanted to include.
The problem is here cause my problem is that normal bug effect, My problem is that i dont understand why this phenomen ( WEIRD NORMAL ONLY WHEN PICKING A SIDE WITH THE CAMERA ) happen, and dont happen when i m changing a layout as explained in my question. Also its a problem for me cause this phenomen is just a symptom of a problem that cause me to not be able to edit the topology as i want with the knife tool thats why im here.

I updated the blendfile

Comment: @Nathan Clarification ; The bug is present only in the "modeling" layout i tested all other layout and its seem fine. Also if u enable backface culling it doesnt appear but other layout doesnt have this option and the weird part is realy that i can't edit the topology as wanted while being in that layout in particular.
What cause that

Comment: did you try to copy and paste your mesh in a new blender file ? I did it with your file and the issue wasn't there anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem it was a simple problem of distance my view parameter was weird cause it have to because my unit scale is based on unreal engine (wich is cm)but i never encounter this case where the knife tool and ur edit mode dont even work properly

Thx @Nathan for trying to help its resolved